# why if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_a] have error?

Tags: python, pygame

[image: view image]

Why is this error happening

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))
while 1:
   hi=pygame.key.get_pressed()
   if hi[K_a]:
   print('done!')
```

Comment: Reading the error message is usually a start when trying to find the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to either do

```
if hi[pygame.K_a]:
```

or

```
from pygame.locals import *
if hi[K_a]:
```

Otherwise `K_a` won't be defined.